# Bootstrap Align Element

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I want to stick an element to the left of its cell in bootstrap but have no idea on how to do it (and tried every possible solution the web offers).
It looks pretty good when the screen is big enough:

[image: big]

but the right arrows wont stick to the label left to them when the screen gets smaller:

[image: small]

```css
body {
  font-size: 13px;
  font-family: Lato;
  letter-spacing: 0.015em;
  word-spacing: 0.03em;
  line-height: 1.5em;
  background: linear-gradient(rgba(95, 102, 116, 0.8), rgba(73, 80, 95, 0.41)), url("images/carbon_fibre.png");
  background-attachment: fixed;
}
.textLabel {
  font-size: 15px;
  padding: 8px;
  background-color: blue;
}
}
```

```html
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div id="row1" class="row text-center">

    <!--- Position X--->
    <div class="col-md-5 col-md-offset-1 col-sm-5 col-sm-offset-1 col-xs-5 col-xs-offset-1">
      <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-2">
        <button id="PositionXdec" class="btn btn-default">&#x276E;</button>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-8 col-sm-8 col-xs-8">
        <p class="text-center textLabel" id="positionX">X</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-2">
        <button id="PositionXinc" class="btn btn-default">&#x276F;</button>
      </div>
    </div>

    <!--- Rotation X --->
    <div class="col-md-5 col-xs-5">
      <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-2">
        <button id="RotationXdec" class="btn btn-default">&#x276E;</button>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-8 col-sm-8 col-xs-8">
        <p class="text-center textLabel" id="RotationX">RX</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-2">
        <button id="RotationXinc" class="btn btn-default text-left">&#x276F;</button>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I think the padding of the columns will prevent the elements from sticking to the left. Also post your CSS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when [nesting columns](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-nesting) in bootstrap you need to add `.row` between `.col-*-*`

**EDIT**

After adding your CSS, you may need to add `col-xs-offset` to your middle `div`

**NOTE**

if you going to have the same `col` *behavior* from `xs` to `md`/`lg`, then you can just use the `xs` class

```css
body {
  font-size: 13px;
  font-family: Lato;
  letter-spacing: 0.015em;
  word-spacing: 0.03em;
  line-height: 1.5em;
  background: linear-gradient(rgba(95, 102, 116, 0.8), rgba(73, 80, 95, 0.41)), url("images/carbon_fibre.png");
  background-attachment: fixed;
}
.textLabel {
  font-size: 15px;
  padding: 8px;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div id="row1" class="row text-center">

    <!--- Position X--->
    <div class="col-xs-5 col-xs-offset-1">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-2">
          <button id="PositionXdec" class="btn btn-default">&#x276E;</button>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-offset-1 col-xs-7">
          <p class="text-center textLabel" id="positionX">X</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-2">
          <button id="PositionXinc" class="btn btn-default">&#x276F;</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <!--- Rotation X --->
    <div class="col-xs-5">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-2">
          <button id="RotationXdec" class="btn btn-default">&#x276E;</button>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-offset-1 col-xs-7">
          <p class="text-center textLabel" id="RotationX">RX</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-2">
          <button id="RotationXinc" class="btn btn-default text-left">&#x276F;</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Then I really don't know what is your problem, seems fine here, do you want space between arrows like your first Screenshot right?

Comment: I just want to have the same space between the label and the left/right arrow. Right now the space between the left arrow and the label gets less (when scaling the window) while the space between the right arrow and the label stays the same.

Comment: not in my snippet..http://easycaptures.com/fs/uploaded/1046/3166279394.png

Comment: Ok, I tried it with another development environment and it worked.
Seems like brackets live-preview caused the issue...

Comment: Thanks for your time and help